# how to get src at run time when streaming multimedia to support ajax functionality

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, struts2

I'm working on Gallery module using struts 2. To show images/Audio/Video files on browser I'm using ajax which will reduce the server load. For ajax call when the page loads i'll just get the src location and set it on object tag(IE) or embed tag(other browsers). This process requiers the file to be in the scope of server. Now what the problem is when the war file is redployed all uploaded files get deleted. How can i show an audio/video file using ajax when the file resides out of server(EAP JBOSS) directory?

Comment: connection pool + database?

Comment: i'm not storing files in DB. now inside the JBOSS_HOME, but have to implement storing and retriving from hard drive which is outside JBOSS_HOME...

Comment: Your application needs to store where those files are someplace... you either configure your application to contain a path where it will search for these files and build an index or you will use a DB to store the file details. You'll find a lot of people store the file details in a DB and keep the files in the file system. Personally I think it's more portable and just a touch easier to put everything in the DB. It's as easy to put a BLOB in the database as a String for the path...

Comment: i finally done it with providing src as a an action and returned the file stream.. It worked for me.... thanks for ur valuable replies....